# How to prevent CommunicationsException?

Tags: java, session, jdbc, timeout

I am currently working with an app which using two different DB(different instance).
DB A is totally under A's project, however DB B is under the other project.(I am managing these via gcloud app engine.)

What is my problem :
DB B always disconnected if no request more than few hours with below error message.

```
{"timestamp":1555464776769,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException","message":"Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 43,738,243 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 43,738,243 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.","path":"/client/getAllCompany"}
```

To resolve this issue, I tried.

1) add 'autoReconnect=true' at application.properties

```
api.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://google/projectB?cloudSqlInstance=projectB:australia-southeast1:projectB&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true
```

2) add below config at application.properties.

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=3600000
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-evictable-idle-time-millis=7200000
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-query=SELECT 1
```

(My project doesn't have web.xml file)

If i re-deploy this project, i can access data from DB B as well.

How can I config to prevent killed the connectivity with DB B?
Wish to listen advice. Thank you in advanced.

HibernateConfig Code for DB B

```
@Bean(name = "apiDataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "api.datasource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean(name = "apiEntityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean apiEntityManagerFactory(
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("apiDataSource") DataSource dataSource
) {
    return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.workspez.api.entity").persistenceUnit("api").build();
}

@Bean(name = "apiTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager apiTransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("apiEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory apiEntityManagerFactory
) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(apiEntityManagerFactory);
}

@Bean(name = "apiJdbc")
public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate apiJdbcTemplate() {
    return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource());
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you are keeping your connections open for too long without returning them to the pool. Without code we can't be sure though

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Hi Sir, thank you for your comment so much. I newly added my config for DB B.